# Storing a value

Tags: netlogo

A classroom is simulated where appliances (e.g lights Fans and ACs) turn on when a student sits next to it. Each appliance has its own wattage rating. When an appliance is turned on its color changes to green and the on-time is noted and the duration on-time is stored. But if a student sits next to a appliance (e.g light) that is already on. The duration-on-time should not be stored as it would be a repetition.

```
     globals[
          simulation-timer

     to appliance-on

           ask students [ ask lights in-radius 4
           [ifelse not already-on?
            [ set color green

            set light-on-time ticks
            set light-on-duration light-on-duration + (time - ticks)
            show (word "light on duration = " light-on-duration)
            set already-on? true] [
            set light-on-duration light-on-duration]]]
```

In this code the light-on-duration is not adding for all of the lights. Only individual light-on-duration is shown. How should I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a logic problem rather than a coding problem. You can't add to duration when the light turns on because it hasn't yet built up any duration. Here is a complete model that turns lights on and off and stores duration. I am using `ticks` as the time, and each tick it adds 5 students and removes 5 students. But what's important is the logic of turning the lights on and off.

```
globals [light-radius]

breed [students student]
students-own
[ desk
]

breed [lights light]
lights-own
[ on?
  turned-on
  duration-on
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set light-radius 3
  ask patches [ set pcolor white ]
  ask patches with [pxcor mod 3 = 0 and pycor mod 3 = 0]
  [ sprout-lights 1
    [ set size 0
      set on? false
      set pcolor gray
    ]
  ]

  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 30 patches
  [ sprout-students 1 
    [ set color blue
    ]
    ask lights in-radius light-radius [switch-light-on]
  ]
end

to go
  repeat 5 [student-arrive]
  repeat 5 [student-leave]
  ask lights with [any? students in-radius light-radius]
  [ switch-light-on
  ]
  tick
end

to student-arrive
  ask one-of patches with [not any? students-here]
  [ sprout-students 1
    [ set color blue
      ask lights in-radius light-radius with [not on?]
      [ switch-light-on
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to switch-light-on
  set pcolor yellow
  set on? true
  set turned-on ticks
end

to student-leave
  ask one-of students
  [ die
  ]
  ask lights with [ on? and not any? students in-radius light-radius ]
  [ switch-light-off
  ]
end

to switch-light-off
  set pcolor gray
  set on? false
  type "previous duration: " print duration-on
  let how-long ticks + 1 - turned-on
  set duration-on duration-on + how-long
  type "new duration: " print duration-on
end
```

Note that you can't actually see the light `turtles`, I am making the patch turn yellow for on and grey for off. Every third patch has a light.

Comment: Thanks but even in this code that you have shown the light does not turn off and the duration-on is not summing up.

Comment: Must have copied over incorrectly. Try this again. I also added some printout in the turning off so you can see the duration change.

Comment: Thank you. But still this code does not sum up all the duration-on time from the beginning.

Comment: It does if you switch off the lights at the end. Each session of the light being on is added once the light switches off. You need to think about how the code works, and adjust for your specific problem.

Comment: So even if a student sits next to a light that is already on the duration on time for that  light won't be added? Because I want to avoid repetitions.

Comment: yes. look at the code - the timer only starts when a light turns on, and the total time is added when the light turns off. Do not do any additional coding until you understand every bit of this example. Use inspect windows to see what happens each tick etc.

Comment: But the new duration is sometimes decreasing. Shouldn't it always increase as tick goes on. Because new duration is being added.

Comment: yes, it should always increase. I just ran the code and I didn't see any decrease. Why do you think there are? What are you looking at to see decreases?

Comment: previous duration: 7
new duration: 9
previous duration: 3
new duration: 5
This is how it is showing in the command box. The new duration is 9 at first, then it becomes 5 afterwards. So why is it decreasing? Shouldn't it be greater than 9?

Comment: The command box is reporting the duration-on for individual lights. So "previous duration: 7 new duration: 9" mean THAT light had previously been on for 7 ticks and just got switched off after an additional 2 ticks. Then "previous duration: 3 new duration: 5" is a new light. Do a monitor for `sum [duration-on] of lights` to get total duration over all lights. That will always increase. Open `inspect` windows for some lights to see what is happening.